# Getting NaN in DOM when trying interpolation from array with ngFor

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, visual-studio-code, nan

I use the Angular 2 + TypeScript, and I get NaN in **option** tag

app.component.ts:

```
export class AppComponent {
  rooms = {
    type: [
      'Study room',
      'Hall',
      'Sports hall',
      'department room',
      'Service room',
      'Restroom']
  };
```

app.component.html:

```
  <select placeholder="Select an option">
    <option *ngFor="let room-type of rooms.type">{{room-type}}</option>
  </select>
```

I can't figure out what's going on, because I can't debug interpolation and all the binding operations, I just don't know how, and Google-Bing don't help!

I use Visual Studio Code on Windows 10.

That's how it looks like:

[image]

I think it's TypeScript causing this problem, because something is expected to get number variables, but recevies not a number...

Comment: It seems to be a bad idea to use symbol '-' in the variable name

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't use the `-` inside a variable name. It's not allowed in JS/TS, so it's also not allowed in templating. It will try to subtract and causing the `NaN` (not a number):

```
<option *ngFor="let roomType of rooms.type">{{roomType}}</option>
```

Comment: <option *ngFor="let roomType of rooms.type">{{roomType  }}</option>

Comment: @PierreDuc thanks for solving the problem. Also can you answer?.. How to debug binding (2-way, 1-way in-out, interpolation)? Just curious.